# Find Without primary key Table in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my query to find out primary key, foreign key in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
select  * 
from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Know I need to select without primary key table in my database.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME 
NOT IN(
SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE constraint_type = 'Primary Key' )
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

**Edit:** As per the comment from @MarkSinkinson this query will be wrong in case of Null value  `information_schema.table_constraints.table_name`, so I would advice the OP to follow with link added in comment which is

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( object_id ) as SchemaName, name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'tablehasprimaryKey') = 0 
ORDER BY SchemaName, TableName ;
```

to get the list of table not having Primary Key

Know more about this [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176105.aspx) which is a better solution here.

Comment: instead of TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' you can also use TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'

Comment: This missed 151 tables in my database without a primary key...If you have `NULL` values in `Information_schema.table_constraints.table_name` then you'll end up with no results (which is incorrect).

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, yes you are right, I have verified it, looking at the OP question, I gave that answer, I have edited my answer, Thanks :)